# Database structure for big collection of fields in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, rubygems

I'm busy with a rails 4/postgres project that is structured in such a way that requires dozens of fields for a specific object, this being company. Each company would include  fields for eg name, location, header_bg, logo, contact name, contact cell etc so the fields very well could grow in the future. What is the best way to structure this DB.

The way I see it I have 3 options:

1) company table with all these fields in the same table

pros: simple, data all in one place and easy to query

cons: table could get very messy and requires manually editing table structure every time a new field is required

~~~~~~

2) company table with an additional company_options table a foreign key company_id. This table will also hold multiple fields

pros and cons are same as above except this will be more neater structure. Crucial data such as company name will go in company table, other data like location, theme, header_bg etc would go in company_options

~~~~~~

3) company table and a company_meta table. This will follow the Wordpress structure of the post_meta table. So it would have the fields: company_id, meta_key, meta_value. each field would go in its own row

pros: flexible, able to dynamically add options/fields without editing table structure

cons: not a simplistic approach with same data in same columns. would need to custom build this functionality for inserting, updating, validation displaying of data. Unless Rails has such a gem which I can't find?

~~~~~~

Any suggestions or additional options would be appreciated. Are there any rules of thumb for determining the kind of structure needed? I started out with the 1st option out of a matter of simplicity but then started to build the 3rd and the amount of code just didn't seem right for what seems like such a common need.

Thanks!

Comment: If a new field comes to Company table in the future, you should apply it immediately in runtime or you can change your project, recompile it and deploy new version?

Comment: I would be able to recompile and deploy, no immediate sense of urgency with adding fields

Comment: So, you don't need option 3 in this case. It's so sophisticated and you should have a strong reason to use it. I prefer option 2.

Comment: Ok thanks @Gholamali-Irani. Yes option 3 does seem like an over engineered approach for what I need. For anyone else interested, I looked into it more and its called the EAV model approach (entity, attribute, value) and looks like it should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan your database schema for the future:

**Will a company be able to have several phones?**

For repeating information, use a new table:

```
rails g model phone number:string type:string
rails g migration add_company_id_to_phones company:references
```

This way you can add several phones and navigate your database to get each phone.

**Will your field only have one of a kind?**

For example, you might only need one `name` field for each `company`. If this is the case, add it directly to the `companies` table:

```
rails g migration add_fields_to_companies name:string
```

**Is your data completely optional? Is it unstructured?**

Add a JSONB field to your table, assuming you are using Postgresql:

```
rails g migration add_details_to_companies details:jsonb
```

With JSONB data type you can use unstructured data like this:

```
Company.create({
  name: "AwesomeCompanyCorp", 
  details: {
    "main phone": "000-0000-0000",
    "secondary phone": "000-0000-0000",
    "support email": "support email",
    "location": "Main Avenue 165",
    "latitude": "22.330213123",
    "longitude": "60.000012312"
  } 
})
```

With JSONB you are able to have unstructured data, but be able to query the field like this:

```
Company.where("details->>'main phone' = ?", "000-0000-0000")
```

With this on mind, choose the best approach that fits your case.

Comment: hey Pablo, thanks for that thorough answer! Is there any kind of best practice to determine when to use that JSONB field as opposed to seperating into different fields?

Comment: I would evaluate the importance of that data. If it only needs to store details, you don't need to query a lot on those fields, and it  changes structure from time to time, I would go for JSONB. If you have data that you will be querying a lot, and that is the same for everyone, I'd probably go for fields for single data entries and multiple fields.

Comment: For example, if you need to store a company's Fax number, but only a low percentage of all the companies have Fax numbers, then it would be an overkill to have a field for Fax numbers. Instead get a field for unstructured details. If you look up PostgreSQL documentation, you'll see that JSONB provides some of the querying capacities of fields and tables. :)